# POST request variables not coming through in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm new to Sails, so I may be doing this wrong, but I can't seem to get data from my form in the controller.

The submit action routes to the proper controller method.

```
<form action="/create" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Controller action:

```
save: function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.param('title'));
    console.log(req.params.all());
}
```

Results in:

```
undefined
{}
```

How am I supposed to get the submitted form data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you omit the name attribute.

```
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title">
```

Without this the parameter can't be received from the server.